# Marginal Costs of Supplying Space to Space Market and the 4Q Model - Property Investment

Tags: microeconomics

In analysis of the Property Investment Market Supply and Demand Curve, the Supply Curve is kinked, reflecting the high inelasticity of supply in the short run. The Supply Curve rises after the Kink, representing the Long Run Marginal Cost of Supplying additional space to the property market (this can be due to land acquisition costs, or increased costs due to building vertically upwards in skyscrapers). This implies, that, the marginal cost of adding more space (or the price of property required to induce more construction) is dependent on the current amount of space in the property market.

[image: Supply Curve showing rising Long Run Marginal Cost of adding more space]

However, the 4 Quadrant Model used to analyse shocks to the Property market holds the minimum cost to induce construction constant, regardless of the stock level in the market. The model shows how the amount of construction varies according to the current market price/sqm, and ignores what the current amount of space in the market is. Is there a contradiction here?

I have used the textbook, Commercial Real Estate and Analysis, by Geltner, Miller, Clayton and Eichholtz, the Supply Curve is in chapter 1 and 4Q model in chapter 2
[image: 4 Quadrant Model]